# Evaluate $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{-2n}}}$ to arbitrary precision

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algorithms

How does one compute the constant
$$K=\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{-2n}}}$$
to an arbitrary number of decimal places? This constant comes from the CORDIC algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) which is used to approximate the sine and cosine. According to Wikipedia,
$$K=0.60725\ldots,$$
but I don't know how they came up with the decimal expansion. Obviously one can truncate the defining infinite product, so that
$$K\approx\prod_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{-2n}}}$$
for some big $N$, but unfortunately this product only gives a sequence of **upper** bounds. When one truncates the product, one has no idea how many digits of the decimal expansion are correct.

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is but rearranging the product we have $K^2 = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{4^n+1}$ so you can maybe perform some kind of analysis on the product expansion? Not sure...

Comment: You can take $\ln K$ and then use a Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x_n)$ where $x_n = 2^{-2n}$. [This article](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/22/tm1212.pdf) may also be of interest to get better $\ln x$ approximations.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^N \ln (1+x_n)\right)$ produces a sequence of upper bounds only as well, I don't know how that logarithm helps.

Comment: @japjap No because you can take a bounding like $\lvert \ln(1+x_n) -a_n \rvert \lt \epsilon_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n$ converges and is as small as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lower bound for any factor is
$$1-2^{-2n-1}\lt\frac1{\sqrt{1+2^{-2n}}}$$
A lower bound for the product of all the left hand sides starting at $n=N+1$, or $1-2^{-2N-3}$, is
$$1-2^{-2N-3}-2^{-2N-5}\cdots\\=
1-{2^{-2N-3}}(1+\frac14+\frac1{16}\cdots)\\
=1-\frac{2^{-2N-1}}3$$
Multiply that by your current estimate to get a lower bound.

Comment: But $1-\frac{1}{3\times 2^{-2N-1}}$ approaches $-\infty$ as $N\to\infty$, isn't that weird?

Comment: Oops, well spotted

Comment: I'm working on a hyperbolic version of CORDIC. It requires evaluating a similar constant, namely $K'=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2^{-2n}}}.$ Do you have any idea how to produce a sequence of **upper bounds** for this constant? I'm having a hard time finding it out: unlike in the case of $1/\sqrt{1+x}$, the Taylor series of $1/\sqrt{1-x}$ at $x=0$ does not alternate.

Comment: @japjap You can use the explicit formulas for the remainder paragraph of [Taylor's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) to get the bound you're looking for.

Comment: @Somos are you interested by https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/264134/desmostutu?tab=profile an uncommon nested radicals ?

Answer (score 2):

$$K(a)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^{-n}}}$$
$$\frac 1{[K(a)]^2}=\prod_{n=0}^\infty(1+a^{-n})=\left(-1;\frac{1}{a}\right)_{\infty }$$

Using series
$$\frac 1{[K(a)]^2}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\, a^{-n}$$ where the first coeffcients
$$\{1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,18,22,27,32,38,46,54,64,76,89,104,122,142,165,192,222,256,296,340,390,448,512,585,668,760,864,982,1113,1260,1426\}$$ obey a linear reccurence equation of degree $11$ with very small integer coefficients (*to be finished, I hope and wish*).

Using the terms given in the table leads, for $a=4$,
$$K=\frac{2199023255552}{\sqrt{13113553710390490783173161}}$$ which is an absolute error of $6.49\times 10^{-24}$.

Using $82$ terms as @Somos reduces the error to $3.35\times 10^{-46}$ which is less accurate than @Somos result.

**Edit**

The coefficients form sequence $A000009$ in $OEIS$.

Answer (score 1):

The question asked

> How does one compute the constant
> $$K=\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{-2n}}}$$
> to an arbitrary number of decimal places?

Define the sequence of finite products

$$ K_n(q) := \prod_{k=0}^n \frac1{\sqrt{1+q^k}}. \tag1 $$

If $\,|q|<1,\,$ this sequence converges to the limit

$$ K(q) := \lim_{n\to\infty} K_n(q). \tag2 $$

Define $\,Q := q^{n+1}.\,$ The result using the method
of undetermined coefficients is

$$ K_n(q) = K(q)\Big(1 + \frac12 \frac{Q}{(1-q)} +
 \frac18\frac{Q^2(-1+3q)}{(1-q)(1-q^2)} +\\
 \frac1{16}\frac{Q^3(1-2q-2q^2+5q^3)}{(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)}
+ \cdots\Big). \tag3 $$

The question is asking about the case where $\,q=1/4\,$
which is in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A273413) excerpted below

> A273413 Decimal expansion of Product_{k>=0} (1 + 1/2^(2k))^(-1/2).

> COMMENTS  This constant is multiplied into the CORDIC algorithm to obtain the correct sine or cosine. See p. 647 of the fxtbook (below).

> EXAMPLE 0.60725293500888125616944675250492826311239085215008977245...

Suppose an accuracy of $50$ decimal digits is required. Note
that $\, \frac12\frac1{1-1/4}(1/4)^{83} \approx .7\times 10^{50}.\,$

The required approximation is
$$ K_{82}(1/4) \approx 0.60725293500888125616944675250492826311239085215009. $$

Comment: "The result is [...]" How did you obtain it?

Comment: @japjap Thanks for that comment! I will have to fix the result now.